# Creating Stored Procedures and joining tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a database called salesshort used mostly for learning MySQL. I am trying to create a stored procedure but for some odd reason when I run my code is not even creating the store procedure I think my syntax is wrong.

here are the instructions and my code.

Create a stored procedure ‘gbSaleP’ that returns the following ‘order types’:
"we are loosing money" if the actual profit for each order (i.e., OrderNumber)- is lower than or equal to zero; "good sale" if the difference between potential profit and actual profit is $2500 or lower; and
"bad sale" if the difference between potential profit and actual profit is greater than $2500.

```
delimiter //

create procedure gbSaleP ( in orderNumber int(10), out SaleStatus varchar (40))
begin
    set gbsaleP = (select sum(o.quantityOrdered*p.MSRP - o.quantityOrdered*p.buyPrice) - abs(sum(o.quantityOrdered*o.priceEach - o.quantityOrdered*p.buyPrice))
from orderdetails as o
join products as p
using(productCode)
group by orderNumber
having porderNumber = orderName);

if gbSaleP <= 2500 then set SalesStatus = "good sale"
elseif gbSaleP => 2500 then set SaleStatus = "bad sale"
else set gbSaleP = "unknown"
end if;

end;
delimiter //
```

Comment: I could not see the `orderNumber` coming from input in your script. First, you should be sure that you calculated the amount correctly.

Comment: Note that 'loosing' means 'to simmer'

Comment: The last end should be followed by // and the delimiter reset to ; the result of what you have is sql does not recognise that the procedure is done and is not compiling fix this then fix the errors..

Answer (score 1):

If your amount calculation script is right, you may use below.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE procedure gbSaleP (IN orderNumber int(10), OUT SaleStatus varchar (40))

BEGIN

   DECLARE amount DECIMAL(20,2);
    set amount = (/*.......Correct SQL script*/);
    
   if amount <= 2500 then 
     set SaleStatus = 'good sale';
   elseif amount > 2500 then 
     set SaleStatus = 'bad sale';
   else 
     set SaleStatus = 'unknown';
   end if;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

You can test it with:

```
CALL `gbSaleP` (7, @`SaleStatus`);
SELECT @SaleStatus;
```

Comment: So its creating it and its stored in my Soted Procedures, but when I try to call it its giving me a Error Code: Unkown Column 'porderNumber' in 'having clause', which makes sense? the porderNumber is not a column in my table but its the column that I am creating in the create procedure statement. basically the porderNumber will = the actual column for orderNumber in my data base and that way I can call it. Idk if I make any sense.

Comment: This the part of `Correct Sql script` part of my answer. Maybe, you should create a ilttle sample of your tables to clarify your structure.